# Как показывать только по три позиции из маркированного списка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Есть маркированный список. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вывести в блоке показ только первых трех позиции, а по кнопке первые три менять на последующие три, и так далее по три по кругу? Если у нас, например, в списке 10 позиций, и поэтому при первом клике на кнопку показываются позиции с 4 по 6, при последующем клике с 7 по 9, при последующем клике оставшаяся позиция из всего списка, т.е. только 10, при последующем клике снова по кругу с 1 по 3, и т.д. Возможно ли такое реализовать? Спасибо!

```html
<div class="block">
<ul class="ulblock">
<li class="liblock">1 позиция</li>
<li class="liblock">2 позиция</li>
<li class="liblock">3 позиция</li>
<li class="liblock">4 позиция</li>
<li class="liblock">5 позиция</li>
<li class="liblock">6 позиция</li>
<li class="liblock">7 позиция</li>
<li class="liblock">8 позиция</li>
<li class="liblock">9 позиция</li>
<li class="liblock">10 позиция</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="knop">Дальше</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$('.liblock').hide();
var start = 0;
var step = 3;
$('.liblock').slice(start, step).show();
$('.knop').on('click', function() {
  $('.liblock').slice(start, start + step).hide();
  if ((start + step) >= $('.liblock').length) start = 0;
  else start += step;
  $('.liblock').slice(start, start + step).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <ul class="ulblock">
    <li class="liblock">1 позиция</li>
    <li class="liblock">2 позиция</li>
    <li class="liblock">3 позиция</li>
    <li class="liblock">4 позиция</li>
    <li class="liblock">5 позиция</li>
    <li class="liblock">6 позиция</li>
    <li class="liblock">7 позиция</li>
    <li class="liblock">8 позиция</li>
    <li class="liblock">9 позиция</li>
    <li class="liblock">10 позиция</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="knop">Дальше</div>
```